# Enumeration to Brush IValueConverter throws an exception attempting to cast System.String to IValueConverter?

Tags: wpf, exception, data-binding, enums, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to convert an enumeration into a brush so that an enum variable can be used to control the color of some control

My enumeration (not really relevant):

```
public enum Colors {
        Red, Blue,
    }
```

Here is my converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Colors), typeof(Brush))]
public class EnumToBrushConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return (Brushes.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here I'm attempting to use it to change the color of a label based on the value of the enum (Color is a public property of type Colors):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <conv:EnumToBrushConverter x:Key="EnumToBrushConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="fixed" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color, Converter=EnumToBrushConverter}" />
</Grid>
```

When the window is constructed, I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message='Set property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Converter' threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '11'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=9
  LinePosition=11
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at TestCollectionChangingListbox.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in c:\Users\stevez\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestCollectionChangingListbox\TestCollectionChangingListbox\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
       at TestCollectionChangingListbox.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\stevez\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestCollectionChangingListbox\TestCollectionChangingListbox\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 29
  InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
       Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'.
       Source=PresentationFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<Create_BamlProperty_Binding_Converter>b__14c(Object target, Object value)
            at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access your converter as a static resource; try this:

```
<Label Content="fixed" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBrushConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need to create an instance of that converter in the resources section of the relevant control (or in the app.xaml file if you want to use the converter in several places in your application):

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:EnumToBrushConverter x:Key="EnumToBrushConverter " />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then reference that converter as a static resource:

```
<Label Content="fixed" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBrushConverter}" />
```